# Exploding a list in Hive SQL to identify blanks

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I have a column called part_nos_list as array<\string> in a hive table. Apparently that column has blank and I want to update that with a '-'. The code sort of does that but 42 rows in a group by has shown having blanks. I tried to check individual records but am not successful. Here is the hive sql. Is there something wrong here in this sql

```
SELECT order_id, exploded_part_nos
FROM   sales.order_detail LATERAL VIEW explode(part_no_list) part_nos AS exploded_part_nos where sale_type in ('POS', 'OTC' , 'CCC') and exploded_part_nos = ''
```

However this group by sql shows 42 as blanks

```
select * from (SELECT explo,count(*) as uni_explo_cnt 
FROM sales.order_detail 
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(concat_ws("##", part_no_list),'##')) yy AS explo where sale_type in ('POS', 'OTC' , 'CCC') group by explo order by explo asc) DD
```

Here is what hive table looks like

```
Id Part_no_list
1  ["OTC","POS","CCC"]
2  ["OTC","POS"]
4  NULL
5
6  ["-"]
7  ["OTC","POS","CCC"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some data examples. Also it's not clear where the 42 columns are

Comment: Sorry leftjoin, I meant rows. I dont know why I said columns. You can assume a table say myHiveTable with just 2 columns Id String, part_no_list array<string>. Typically a null column, blank columns and few other values in column should be filled with a hypen '-', so that the UI can filter those by default. Looking at the code, it looks like job is being. Tried the first sql, no records with blanks showed up. But I received another sql which is 2nd one, which shows 42 rows with part_no_list as blank. This is on cloudera. I am using Hive to run the sql (not impala). Is first hive sql correct

Comment: Please provide what part_no_list contains

Comment: I want to identify row 5

Comment: What is your 5th row??? It cannot be just blank. it should always be an array. Array of one blank element looks like [] not just blank

Comment: oh Is it. I am not able to view that record and I thought it should be like. Let me look for it. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to easily pull that row ? Will the 1st sql in my original post show me that row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190110/discussion-between-user1509593-and-leftjoin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if exploded array element is empty, use this:

```
select * from(
select explode( array("OTC","POS","CCC",""))  as explo 
) s where explo=''
```

Result is one empty string.

If you want to identify array containing empty element use `array_contains`:

```
select * from(
select array("OTC","POS","CCC","")  as a
) s where array_contains(a,'')
```

Result:

```
["OTC","POS","CCC",""]
```

If you want to find array containing only one element - empty string use `size(array)=1` or `array_contains(array,'')`

**But there is also such thing as an empty array**.
It displayed the same as array containing empty element but it is not the same.

And to find empty array, use `size()=0`
Example:

```
select * from(
select array()  as a
) s where size(a)=0
```

Returns `[]`

Run all these queries on your data and you will become enlightened. I think it is empty arrays, not empty element in your case

Empty array is not NULL, because it is still an array object of zero size:

```
select * from(
select array()  as a
) s where a is null
```

Returns no rows

Better query array only without explode and use `array_contains` and `size` to find empty arrays and empty elements. Use LATERAL VIEW **OUTER** to generate rows even when a LATERAL VIEW usually would not generate a row.  LATERAL VIEW without OUTER word works as INNER JOIN, see docs about [LATERAL VIEW OUTER](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView#LanguageManualLateralView-OuterLateralViews)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help in writing the query. This looks good and I am going to accept the answer. I am assuming the table name from order_detail is going in the inner select. Is that correct ? If that is the case, would you mind added that so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: @user1509593 Only you know for sure what exactly the case is, because I have no your data ans cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thank you leftjoin. My goal was to make it useful to other. I put the table name in the inner select